# The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method

Tags: paw-app

When I'm adding anything to the body of my request to S3 I'm getting "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method."
http://take.ms/7OUBj
If I'm not adding anything to the body I'm getting 200 OK response
https://monosnap.com/file/IdUri82LNTkZIB90lM26JxT0IPINcD

Where is the problem?